# How to assign array values equally to three separate divs

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array containing car features. I'm using a bootstrap grid system and would like to list these array elements out in three col-md-4 divs so they look like this:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    Air Conditioning<br />
    Power Windows<br />
    Power Locks<br />
    Power Steering<br />
    Tilt Wheel<br />
    AM/FM CD/MP3
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    Satellite<br />
    Immobilizer<br />
    Keyless Entry<br />
    Alarm<br />
    Daytime Running Lights<br />
    Dual Front Airbags
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    Side Airbags<br />
    Head Airbags<br />
    Rear Head Airbags<br />
    Active Seatbelts<br />
    All Wheel ABS<br />
    Power Sun/Moon Roof
</div>
```

From a list like this:

```
<?php
$feature_list = "Air Conditioning; Power Windows; Power Locks; Power Steering; Tilt Wheel; AM/FM CD/MP3; Satellite; AM/FM CD/DVD; Immobilizer; Keyless Entry; Alarm; Daytime Running Lights; Dual Front Airbags; Side Airbags; Head Airbags; Rear Head Airbags; Active Seatbelts; All Wheel ABS; Power Sun/Moon Roof;"

$feature_list = explode(';', $feature_list);
?>
```

How would I go about looping through the array in a way that evenly assigns these array values to the divs?

Comment: Loop through the array

Comment: chunk springs to mind...

Comment: @Rizier123 edited question

Comment: @Popnoodles What do you mean?

Comment: Part of programming is about finding the answers. Googling **the tags you added + chunk** would have been a good start for finding the solution. Regardless, I posted an answer.

Comment: You'd have to admit though, googling 'chunk' is not quite as obvious as you make it sound to someone who is still feeling out the language.

Comment: Really? https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?q=php%20arrays%20chunk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87192/discussion-between-shane-and-popnoodles).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to do that.

```
// split array into three arrays. The last may have fewer items than the rest.
$feature_list_columns = array_chunk($feature_list, (int)(count($feature_list) / 3));
```

You didn't say how you were outputting them but this would work

```
$output = '';
foreach ($feature_list_columns as $column){
    $output .= '<div class="col-md-4">' . implode("<br />", $column) . '</div><!--/.col-md-4-->';
}
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <?php 
$feature_list = "Air Conditioning; Power Windows; Power Locks; Power Steering; Tilt Wheel; AM/FM CD/MP3; Satellite; AM/FM CD/DVD; Immobilizer; Keyless Entry; Alarm; Daytime Running Lights; Dual Front Airbags; Side Airbags; Head Airbags; Rear Head Airbags; Active Seatbelts; All Wheel ABS; Power Sun/Moon Roof;";
$feature_list = explode(';', $feature_list);
echo"<div class=\"col-md-4\"> ";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($feature_list); $i++) {
    echo $feature_list[$i]."<br/>";
    if (($i+1)%6==0) {
        echo "</div><div class=\"col-md-4\"> ";
    }
}
echo "</div>";
?>
```